# Rocketchat production grade, still a good choice for deployment with Meteor Galaxy?

Tags: meteor, rocket.chat, meteor-galaxy

Is it still advisable to deploy a production grade version of Rocket.Chat using Meteor Galaxy as the Host?  I am also using a MongoDb Atlas with a replica set as the host.
I found this:  https://martinschoeler.github.io/docs/installation/paas-deployments/galaxy/  and have had success deploying it.  However, I'm concerned about going a direction that isn't advised anymore.

I'm going to use the lastest stable release (3.2.2) and am getting a little nervous about doing this without seeing the branded Galaxy choice on the page of deployment choices under 'Server Install' here:

https://rocket.chat/install

Answer (score 0):

Galaxy is still the most stable and reliable form of deployment for a Meteor application. It is not listed on the main install page, but the guide still exists: https://docs.rocket.chat/installation/paas-deployments/galaxy